# PHP find the node by value and remove it XML

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have all properties listed in XML file with this structure

```
<property>
  <details>
        <object>25.5 m2 Flat in New York</object>
  </details>
</property>
<property>
  <details>
        <object>95.6 m2 House in New Jersey</object>
  </details>
</property>
```

Now I want to use PHP to find the node with a specific `<object>` value and to remove the parent node (`<property>`). **How can I do it?**

I tried by doing the code below but I cannot manage to work.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('../openimmo/xml-import1.xml');

$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;

$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('property');

$nodeToRemove = null;
foreach ($list as $domElement) {
    $attrValue = $domElement->getElementsByTagName('object');
    foreach ($attrValue as $item) {
        if ($item->nodeValue == $_GET['delete']) {
            $nodeToRemove = $domElement;
        }
    }
}

if ($nodeToRemove != null)
$thedocument->removeChild($nodeToRemove);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: It is a lot easier with simpleXML. Is that available to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Xpath expressions to fetch nodes. This allows you to use conditions.

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
//$document->load('../openimmo/xml-import1.xml');
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$objectText = '25.5 m2 Flat in New York';
$properties = $xpath->evaluate('//property[details/object = "'.$objectText.'"]');
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    // remove the node (PHP 8)
    $property->remove();
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

The other difference is that the result of `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is not live. Unlike the result from `DOMNode::getElementsByTagName()` it does not change if the DOM changes.

PHP 8 adds DOM Living Standard methods. In PHP 7 you would have to use `$property->parentNode->removeChild($property)`.